# Current (2024) best practices for TLS on IIS 10 / Windows Server 2022

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2022, iis-10

Outside of no support for older browsers, are there any reasons not to disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on an IIS webserver? Best to just stick with TLS 1.2 and 1.3 now?

IIS Crypto seems to want to leave 1.0 and 1.1 enabled in their "Best Practices" template.

Any other thoughts/considerations outside of browser support?

Comment: 1. IIS Crypto isn't from Microsoft. 2. If you take Azure as an example, anything other than 1.2/1.3 is going to be deprecated, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-support-tls-will-end-by-31-october-2024-2/

Comment: They are disabled for a reason. They are no longer considered secure. If you are happy for your system to be attacked & hacked, then carry on & enable them.

Comment: 1. All browsers support TLS 1.2. 2. This isn't a forum for discussing a junk craplication that is not and has never been needed. The settings required are and have been well known for many years. You don't need an app that hasn't been updated in years to caution you about breaking Internet Explorer and Windows Vista and Android 4.3. https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/FAQ/Why-does-Best-Practices-still-include-TLS-1.0